# JavaScript: String compared with numeric

Tags: javascript, html, string-comparison, autoboxing, type-conversion

We know that by default, the 'obj' below is string. Without using 'parseInt', how does JavaScript compare it with a number?

```
obj = document.frm.weight.value;
if( obj < 0 || obj > 5 ){
    alert("Enter valid range!");
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If one of the operands of `<` or `>` is number, the other one will be casted to a number.

```
alert("3" > 3);   // false
alert("3.5" > 3); // true
```

**EDIT and further explanation:**

If it is not possible to cast the other parameter into a number, it is casted into the special value called `NaN` - the abbreviation stands for "**N**ot **a** **N**umber". The `NaN` value has a special property that it is absolutely incomparable - all relation operators like `<`, `>` and `=` will return `false` if one of the arguments is `NaN`.

```
alert("" > 3);      // false
alert("3.5?" > 3);  // false
alert({} > 3);      // false
```

Also, note that in the second line, if we used

```
alert(parseInt("3.5?") > 3);
```

it would alert `true`, because `parseInt` reads `"3.5"` from the string `"3.5?"`, then stops reading at `"?"` and thus evaluates to `3.5`. However,

```
alert("3.5?" > 3);
```

returns `false` because the cast from `string` to `number` is not as benevolent as `parseInt`. As `"3.5"` indeed isn't a number, it is casted to `NaN`.

Comment: And if another can be transformed to a number i.e. `(("a" > 5) || ("a" < 5))` is false.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov In this case, the interpreter tries to cast `"a"` to number. As this cannot be done, it is casted to `NaN` - "Not A Number", because indeed `a` is not a number. And any comparison with `NaN` results in false.

Comment: +1. As it is now complete explanation. Consider merging your comment into answer itself.

Answer (score 3):

Well, as an [EMCAScript](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) implementation, Javascript will follow the **Abstract Relational Comparison Algorithm** as defined in the **11.8.5** section of the Ecma-262.

Firstly Javascript will apply to both operands the internal operator `ToPrimitive`, which must return a primitive value (**undefined**, **boolean**, **string**, **null** or **number**) based on the arguments passed to it. If a primitive value is passed to `ToPrimitive` the return value is the argument value passed to the operator, if it's an Object an internal method that all Objects in Javascript implements is called, it's the **[[DefaultValue]]**. 
This method is responsible for returning a primitive type that an Object represents. Depending on the type of code this method may call either `toString` or `valueOf` methods of the Object.

For instance:

```
 var x = {valueOf: function() { return 3; }};

 console.log(x > 2); // true
 console.log(x < 1); // false
 console.log(x == 3); // true
```

How does the Javascript decide which method it should call? Well, the `ToPrimitive` operator may recieve an optional parameter, it's used to give preference to a specific type, e.g. `Number` or `String`. 
If `Number` is passed, the `valueOf` method will be called first, if that method doesn't exist in the Object or doesn't return a primitive type, `toString` is called then. If `String` is passed, the reverse occurs: `toString` is called first, if it neither exists in the Object nor returns a primitive value, `valueOf` is called. 
This is why, in the above snippet, I can compare an Object and a primitive type freely. It's really important to understand when dealing with comparison.


After that, if both operands are `Strings` Javascript will follow some interesting and specific algorithm related to Unicode Standard, checking for code points values. Otherwise, Javascript will cast both operands to `Number` and their mathematical value are compared. Note that if one of them is **NaN** the comparison evaluates to **undefined**, which would be **false** in an `if` statement.

Some examples:

```js
// true => ToNumber(true) > ToNumber(false)
console.log(true > false); 
// true => ToNumber("5") < ToNumber(10)
console.log("5" < 10); 
// false ToNumber(ToPrimitive(obj, Number)) == ToNumber(10)
console.log(({valueOf: function() { return 10}}) > 10); 
// false, it's not related to the length of the strings, 
// the code point value of each char  is used to evaluate the comparison
console.log('Hello worlds' > 'hello');
```

Hope it helps to clarify something.

Answer (score 0):

The string will be cast to a number using arbitrary rules. Typically you'll see rules like this:

- If the string starts with `0x`, treat it as a hexadecimal number.
- If the string starts with `0`, treat it as an octal number. (not in all browsers)
- Otherwise, treat it as decimal.

This means in particular that input like "09" could be confusing to the browser and it may be interpreted as `9` or `0` (because nine is not a valid octal digit).

In general, when comparing a string to a number, you should always manually call `parseInt` with a radix argument of `10`. That way, there are no surprises.