# can I compare a string with a number?

Tags: string, numbers, comparison

I wonder why this works:

```
console.log(34<"345")
```

is true even though the left is a number and the right is a string;
oh and the language is js.

Comment: Which language?

Comment: Assuming JavaScript, values are automatically converted when you use them for some purposes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript: String compared with numeric](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10577789/javascript-string-compared-with-numeric)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's javascript.

When JavaScript tries to operate on a "wrong" data type, it will try to convert the value to a "right" type. Read more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_type_conversion.asp).

Also see more such examples from w3schools [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_type_convert_auto).